# Converting a GIT file system repository to a Bonobo

Tags: git, githooks, bonobo

We have approximately 100 Git repositories in a window server. Which we clone/access simply by

> \\GITrepos\&Repository Name&

We had some problems with it and found out that most of them are solved if I move the repositories to be managed under Bonobo Git server.

I have installed the Bonobo Git Server and directed it to get all repositories from the \\GITrepos folder. I can see all the LDAP users I connected as Users in Bonobo.

I have connected our LDAP groups to be all the users in the Bonobo. I can see all the LDAP users I connected as Users in Bonobo.

I can clone them using the http:/... that Bonobo manages

After answering 1,3 & 4 myself, below. All left for me to do is -

2. How do I prevent the developers from continuing using the \\path\to\Repos method ?

My previous problems solved below:

1 - What is the simplest & recommended way to add all relevant contributors to the correct repository ? I don't feel like going over repository by repository and marking the relevant 10 developers among hundreds in Bonobo UI users list

3 - If I create specific teams and then in the repository configuration under Bonobo UI I mark only the Team and not specific Users, will that allow users to clone/push/pull ? Or, I must add them to the contributors too ?

4 - We are using an 'update' hook to check who is allowed to push to which branch. Is it necessary to use it under Bonobo ? How can I manage the branch authorisation under Bonobo ?

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: Rename the repo to a non-shared server folder, and point Bonobo there.  When the devs cannot pull or push they will update their git url.

Comment: Thanks @Sheepy. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I tried some tests my self and here are my answers, to 3 out of 4 of my questions, for the one left I'll update my basic question.

1. Editing the bonobo's main web.config in something like intpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\Web.config with the relevant teams & corresponding teams in LDAP you'll get to do that job. It will automatically adds the teams to the UI and then all needs to do is mark them to allow clone/push/pull permissions. BUT !! the 'update' hook will control the push permissions for each branch. So thats answers 3 & 4.

3,4. Yes we must still use the 'update' hook to set specific people to push to specific branches. And Yes, marking the team allowing the whole team members to clone.

UPDATE !!

As for question 2 - As @sheepy answered above in the remarks of the question. Removing the shared option on the folder Bonobo points at, force dev to change their URL. Thanks @sheepy

Eli